# in a link list what is the difference between head=something; and head.next=something;

Tags: java, linked-list

Node is defined as

```
class Node {
    int data;
    Node next;
}

Node RemoveDuplicates(Node head) {

    Node temp=head;
    while(temp.next!=null){
        if(temp.data == temp.next.data){
            temp.next=temp.next.next;
        } else { 
            System.out.println(temp.data);
            temp=temp.next;
        }
    }
    return head;
}
```

Comment: what is your question ?

Answer (score 2):

The head is the first value in the list, while head.next is the second value.

For example if my list were `1->2->3` my head would be 1 and my head.next would be 2.
So assigning `head = 5` would turn the list to `5->2->3` this is different from assigning `head.next = 5` which would change the list to `1->5->3`.

Answer (score 1):

`head` presumably is a member of your `LinkedList` class (which you did not show).  It is a *reference* to a `Node` object, the first object in the list.  The statement

```
head = something;
```

presumes that `something` is also a `Node` reference, and it assigns the value of `something` to `head`.  Another way of saying this is that whatever `something` pointed to is now also pointed to by `head`.

The expression `head.next` means to look at the `Node` pointed to by `head` and return the value of the `next` member (which is also a `Node` reference).  On the left hand side of an assignment, as in

```
head.next = something_else;
```

it means to take the value of `something_else` (which must also be a `Node` reference), and assign it to the `next` member of the node currently pointed to by `head`.